# Using YouTube audio link in Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, google-drive-api, alexa-skills-kit

I want to play a audio which comes from YouTube in my skill. I've tried multiple solutions like using youtube-dl and others but the links get expired after a few hours. Also I can rip the audio but how can I get .mp3 links for Alexa skill when I upload them to drive,Dropbox etc?
Fyi- The audio is not licensed or anything so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Please share same code so we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: There is no problem with the code but with the source link of the audio. The code is working fine the only thing to be changed is the stream link in index.js in lamda

Comment: *"The audio is not licensed or anything"* but consider YouTube's terms of service: *"You agree not to distribute in any medium any part of the Service or the Content without YouTube's prior written authorization, unless YouTube makes available the means for such distribution through functionality offered by the Service (such as the Embeddable Player)."*

Comment: I intend to use it for personal stuff and not publish it to the skill store